# Como conectar o Mysql no Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2015

Tenho o Visual Studio 2015, criei um projeto e quero conectar três bancos de dados nele *(Firebird, Paradox e MySql)*, inicialmente o *MySql*.

Criei um novo projeto assim: `C# > Windows > Classic Desktop > Windows Form Aplication` (não sei se é esse mesmo que devo criar, sou iniciante ainda).

Segui [esse](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-making-a-connection.html) tutorial para conectar ao banco de dados.

Nele, sou orientado a clicar em `Server Explorer > Add Connection > Selecionar MySql`

Porém, não aparece essa opção pra mim. Aparecem:

> Access, ODBC, SQL Server e Oracle.

Como faço pra incluir o MySql nessa opção?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisar instalar o provedor de banco de dados do MySQL.

[Aqui esta o link para instalação.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=460645)

Não é necessário fazer o login, basta clicar no link conforme a imagem abaixo, apos baixar, siga os passos do instalador.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apos a instalação reinicie o visual studio e escolhar o Data Source que você que.

Veja a imagem abaixo depois com o que você precisar depois da instalação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Referente a descrição.

> Criei um novo projeto assim: C# > Windows > Classic Desktop > Windows
>   Form Aplication (não sei se é esse mesmo que devo criar, sou iniciante
>   ainda).

Isso você precisar intender melhor o que vai fazer exatamente, cada tipo de projeto levar você a caminhos diferentes.

Comment: obrigado. então eu tenho que encontrar um desse tambem pro firebird e paradox?

Comment: consegui conectar no mysql e no paradox. vou procurar o do firebird. e tambem aprender a manipular as tabelas. valeu mesmo